# x86 instruction to Opcode conversion

Tags: x86, x86-64

`movdqa xmm0, ptr fs:[eax]` and `movdqu (Array[ebx]), xmm0` are the 2 instructions are not executing in my compiler. Please can any tell me the exact opcode for those instruction?

Answer (score 1):

```
movdqa xmm0, ptr fs:[eax]
```

Uses segment override prefix for `FS`, (three-byte) opcode and ModR/M byte. It should look like this:

```
0x64           ;<-- segment override prefix FS
0x66 0x0F 0x6F ;<-- opcode
0x00           ;<-- ModR/M is 000 for Reg (xmm0), 00 for Mod 
               ;(single member addressing) and 000 for Memory ([EAX])
```

Second instruction doesn't use segment override prefix.

```
movdqu (Array[ebx]), xmm0
```

I think I don't understand that first brackets here.
If they mean setting value of `Array[ebx]`, then code should look like this:

```
0xF3 0x0F 0x7F ;<-- opcode
0x80           ;ModR/M is 00 for Reg (xmm0), 10 for Mod
               ;(register+disp32) and 000 for memory ([EAX+disp32])
0xdeadbeef     ;little-endian encoded address displacement for Array
```

If they mean advanced calculation, there's need for SIB byte.